# Unity configuration in separate library

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm developing app with Unity container which has some dependant lib's. I'm configuring Unity at startup of my app. If want to use unity in lib, how and where should i config container?

Comment: Thank you, i've found the answer. @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

I think **UnityContainerExtension** is the best solution i found.